# Miriam's Death in the Midbar

Tags: eretz-yisrael, funeral-burial-levaya, miriam

Why wasn't Miriam's body taken to Eretz Yisrael for burial when she died?
In her merit, the well followed B'Nei Yisrael in the desert. She saved Moshe by taking care of him as a baby in the Nile River.
Didn't she deserve the same treatment as Yosef Ha'Tzadik?

Comment: The same question goes for Moshe and Aharon as well. isn't it?

Comment: Actually, I take it back. God tells Moshe and Aharon where to be buried, but not to Miriam. Good question.

Answer (score 9):

The Meshech Chochmo [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Meshech_Hochma%2C_Khukkat.32?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) answers your question.

He writes:

> ויתכן שמה שהזכיר במרים ותמת שם מרים ותקבר שם, להורות כי השבטים היו נשואים לקוברן בארץ, ומרים לא נשאו לקוברה בארץ, אעפ"י שהיא מתה בחו"ל, מפני שקדש עיר קצה גבול אדום, ולעתיד יתן הקב"ה את קיני, קניזי, קדמוני, שזה אדום, עמון ומואב, א"כ יהיה הכל שייך לא"י, ותהא קבורה בא"י. וכיו"ב אמר בכתובות ירושלמי פרק הנושא על ר' מאיר, שהיה קבור באסיא, שכשיבוא משיח יהא דידכון. יעו"ש. רק השבטים היו צריכים לנושאן ממצרים, לכן הוליכו אותן עד ארץ ישראל, משא"כ מרים מתה שם, **לכן ותקבר שם, כי כשיבוא משיח, הוא לארץ ישראל**, לכן כתב זה ליעד אותו על כל העשר אומות, כי יתקיימו בעה"י בב"א. ודו"ק.

In summary, she died in the region of [Kadesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh_(biblical)#/media/File:Map_Land_of_Israel.jpg) which is on the edges of the borders of Edom. In the future, the land of several nations will be given over to the Jewish people, and her burial in this area is a lasting guarantee that we will be blessed with these lands which will be absorbed into Eretz Yisroel. So whilst she is not currently buried in Israel, in the future this land will become part of Israel.

Comment: Where is this land in the modern day?

Comment: @Prometheus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadesh_(biblical)#Location